# possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0): [axioserror:network error]" , "axioserror network error"

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, axios

I'm trying to communicate with a Node.js backend using React Native, and I'm using axios for this purpose. However, I keep encountering axios errors. To resolve this issue, I've tried numerous attempts. My laptop and Android device are both on the same network. The Postman requests work fine. I've also tried changing the endpoint address multiple times based on Google search results. For example, I've tried using '10.0.2.2' for the emulator and my laptop's IPv4 address for running on a physical device, but it still doesn't work. My laptop runs on Windows. Another team member uses a Mac, and it works well on their laptop. What could be the problem?

error messeage is "possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0): [axioserror:network error]"
or "axioserror network error"

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const templogin = async () => {
      try {
        const loginEndpoint = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/auth/login';
        const loginData = {
          email: 'tickle_user1@example.com',
          password: 'tickle1234~',
        };
  
        axios.post(loginEndpoint, loginData)
          .then(response => {
            const accessToken = response.data.data.access_token;
            console.log('발급된 Token:', accessToken);
            setToken(accessToken);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            if (error.response) {
              // 요청이 이루어졌으며 서버가 2xx의 범위를 벗어나는 상태 코드로 응답했습니다.
              console.log(error.response.data);
              console.log(error.response.status);
              console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
              // 요청이 이루어 졌으나 응답을 받지 못했습니다.
              console.log(error.request);
            } else {
              // 오류를 발생시킨 요청을 설정하는 중에 문제가 발생했습니다.
              console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('로그인 중 오류:', error);
      }
    };
    templogin();
  }, []);
  

  if (!token) {
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: instead of .then() use .catch(). this makes the code easier to read and understand.
when there is an error, the code will now return a loading message or a spinner, indicating that the login process is still ongoing also use netinfo package to check network before u calling any api calls